# How can I split an animated .gif file into its component frames?

Tags: image-processing

How can I easily split an animated .gif file? I want to see each frame.

I would really prefer to not to export every frame to a directory. I'd like to view them individually in one application if possible.

Is this possible on Linux?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try opening them with The Gimp; I believe it will open animated gifs with one layer per frame.

You say you don't want to dump all frames to files on a directory, but I'll tell you how to do it anyway :) install either ImageMagick or graphicsmagick, then:

for ImageMagick:

```
convert animation.gif target.png
```

for graphicsmagick:

```
gm convert animation.gif target.png
```

it'll write frames to target0.png,target1.png,... and so on. You can then enter the directory and run `eog`, it'll show you all the frames on the same application. When you no longer need the frames, just `rm target*.png`.

Comment: imagemagick is just awesome!!

Comment: imagemagic convert failed for me, since it seems that each image of the gif was represented as a new transparent backgrounds layer, and convert gave those transparent layers: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/AstarExample.gif

Comment: I opened my gif in gimp, but I still don't know how to view each frame individually - I just see the last frame.  I'm working with this animation: /tmp/Non-Native-American-Nations-Territorial-Claims-over-NAFTA-countries-1750-2008.gif

Comment: GraphicsMagick needs to be of the form `gm convert some-image.gif +adjoin some-image%d.png` to work. Or, `gm convert some-image.gif -coalesce +adjoin some-image%d.png` for varied sized subframes with varying offsets.

Comment: The specified `convert` misses the `-coalesce` option, which is required for what a user would expect.

Answer (score 56):

If the various frames have transparent areas and build upon each other, you can use the `convert` command with the "`-coalesce`" option to produce a set of files target-0.png, target-1.png etc, each of which merges the sequence of previous images:

```
convert -coalesce animation.gif target.png
```

Comment: Great comment but needs explanation.  Basically it solves the problem @cirosantilli had with ImageMagick returning what looked liked updates to specific screen areas.  -coalesce merges those updates to give you a finished rendering.

Comment: It should be noted that (as of ImageMagick version 6.7.7) there seems to be some memory leak: **do not attempt `-coalesce` with long `.gif` screencasts**, it would probably consume all available memory and possibly hang your entire system.

Comment: you can specify the output file names via something like: `convert -coalesce animation.gif target.%04d.png`

Answer (score 2):

for me, with `ImageMagick` (version info: `6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31`)

```
convert gif.gif gif.pdf
```

makes a pdf with each page being a frame of the input gif, then you can just page through the frames in the pdf viewing application of your choosing

Comment: That seems overly complicated and unlike what OP wants.

Comment: To get each frame as a page in a .pdf is a great idea, just take into consideration that this method might be buggy, and you need to [tweak the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453#48869031).

Answer (score 1):

Use mpv . Open it on desktop . Drag gif into it. Take a screenshot of your desired/single frame with s key. You may even pause if your gif is fast. Very Quick way.

===========

you may want to use these settings first *[once set you do not have to do again]*:

```
gedit ~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf
```

and enter and save:

`--screenshot-format`              Choices: jpg jpeg png (default: jpg)

for highest png quality:

```
--screenshot-format=png
--screenshot-png-compression=9
```

or if you want jpg

`--screenshot-jpeg-quality`        Integer (0 to 100) (default: 90)

Use `mpv --list-options`    for other details

Comment: Hi :) back andrew.46.  tried Gimp and got frustrated. there is not much that mpv cannot do :]