# Zero-padding of output file names in gif->png conversion from ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing

I have used [this great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/101527/362864) to convert a .gif to its constituent frames:

```
convert foo.gif foo.png
```

My intention was to do some edits to the frames on the command line before combining them back as an output gif; unfortunately, the output file names from this first step aren't properly zero-padded, so we're left with:

```
foo-frame-0.png
foo-frame-1.png
# ...
foo-frame-10.png
```

which come up in the wrong order when attempting a clean loop:

```
for FILE in foo-frame-*.png; do echo $F; done
# foo-frame-0.png
# foo-frame-10.png
# foo-frame-1.png
# foo-frame-2.png
# ...
# foo-frame-9.png
```

And the workaround for [this case of renaming the files ex-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700146/3576984) where there's a postfix seems to be quite ugly.

One workaround for this case is the slightly-hacky but basically OK:

```
for FILE in foo-frame-[0-9].png foo-frame-[0-9][0-9]; do echo $F; done
```

(i.e. combine the one-digit, then the two-digit lists)

However, I can't help but wonder if there's any way to get this as the ouput directly from `convert`? I didn't see anything in the `man` page.

An acceptable alternative would be a way to "loop" over the frames of the gif, performing the same action to each. I tried a simple version of this with `convert` but it combined all of the frames into one massive single frame.

Comment: It should be possible to use a `printf`-style `%02d` format specifier - see for example [imagemagick autonumber starting from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185993/imagemagick-autonumber-starting-from-1)

Comment: @steeldriver nailed it, thanks! `foo-frame-%02d.png` works perfectly.